# How do I retrieve data for a specific date in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, select

Let's say if I want to retrieve the closing price for a cryptocurrency on 2022-09-01. I am sure my code is not correct.

```
BTC.todays_price <- BTC.charts$close %>% filter(BTC.charts$date = '2022-09-01')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean `BTC.charts$date == '2022-09-01'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to conditionally select:

```
BTC.charts[BTC.charts$date == '2022-09-01', ]$close
```